# Trying to remove element in embedded Facebook video / iFrame

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, iframe

## Problem

Trying to remove the following div `_2za- _-l3` from a Facebook embedded video to hide the details regarding title, posted by and viewcount. While it seems to work in the developer tools, when I try to target it in my css, even going as far as `display: none !important;` doesn't seem to change it.

### Embed

```
            <div id="fb-root"></div><script>(function(d, s, id) {  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script><div class="fb-video" data-allowfullscreen="1" data-href="/thebrandonsun/videos/p.10153950906309750/10153950906309750/?type=3"></div>
```

Comment: After it loads the iframe you can hook the div using JQuery and just hide it by $(div).hide()

Comment: why use jquery for the simple task of hiding something?

Comment: anyway, you are not allowed to hide any part of facebooks plugins